# How to remove grey/black artifacts at the edges of a png with transparent background image using ImageMagick

Tags: java, imagemagick

I've noticed that there are a few black or gray pixels along the edges of my png image with transparent background, and I'd like to clean them up using ImageMagick.

Could you provide some guidance on how to remove these black or gray edge pixels while ensuring that other black or gray pixels within the image are not affected?

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: How is this question related to *java*?

Comment: This is odd. I think it is a browser issue.  I see your black areas when I first view it in my Safari browser. But when I drag and drop your image to my desktop and then refresh my browser, I do not see them any longer. Then when I trash my desktop copy of the file and refresh the browser, they come back. It is probably an issue with partial transparency pixels and the way the browser handles them.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, firstly I don't see any black or grey pixels in your image at the edges or elsewhere?

If I flatten your image onto a lime background, I should be able to see them:

```
magick glow.png -background lime -flatten result.png
```

[image]

Let's look at your image's constituent channels by separating them out and laying them out R, G, B, A across the page with a 10 px gap between channels:

```
magick glow.png -separate +smush 10 channels.png
```

[image]

Let's assume your question really wants to slightly increase the size of the transparent area (i.e. the black surround in the right-most channel) so that we don't see the jagged edges of the other (RGB) channels. We can do that by eroding the white area slightly:

```
magick glow.png -resize 400x -channel A -morphology erode disk:20 result.png
```

[image]

If we separate out the channels again, you can see what has happened in the alpha channel on the right:

```
magick result.png -separate +smush 10 channels.png
```

[image]

I have exaggerated the effect by reducing the size of your enormous image and using a large disk. You should experiment with the disk size till you get the result you need.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Setchell. I don't want to do resize. Does below command works ?

magick glow.png -channel A -morphology erode disk:20 result.png

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you resize. It's just that, if you have a 5000 pixel wide image, you will barely see the effect of a 3px erosion, and if you make the disk 200px, you'll be waiting 15 minutes. As I said, experiment with the disk size - I can't see any problem that needs fixing on my machine anyway.

Comment: The problem still exists even after magick glow.png -channel A -morphology erode disk:20 result.png . Please let me know your ideas.

Comment: Are you using the exact image you shared above? Have you tried changing `disk:20` to `disk:100`? Did you try flattening the PNG onto a coloured background before and again after the command I suggested?

Comment: I tried the flattening and it is fixing the issue but it is adding the white background. I am not able to remove that white background. Please let me know your ideas.

Comment: Try changing the word `erode` to `dilate` and see if that makes the issue (which I still cannot see) worse. By the way, I asked you to clarify 3 things above and you only answered one

Comment: I tried dilate, it thickened the edges and it made things worse. I tried erode with disk:100 and ImageMagick took loot of time to process the image and it didn't fix the issue. Please let me know your ideas.